# How to implement a method that will process Timeouts of a service in a asychronous manner?

Tags: java, asynchronous, timeout, threadpool, executorservice

Lets say you have a process that needs to continuously check the time of a "Service". I want to to design this process to eliminate and log a "Service" that is about to timeout from a thread safe list.

What would be a good way to keep checking a CopyOnWriteArrayList of type "Services" for timeouts?

- Keep in mind other "systems" may need to add a service to the list at any time. So we must keep checking for the duration of what ever process is adding another service to the list.

```
Consumer(){
//some method that adds service objects to the list."
}

public class Service(){
// time would represent the time it was created by some system.
int time;
// unique id of service.
String id;
}

public class ServiceTimeoutProcesser{
private CopyOnWriteArrayList inputCopyOnWriteArrayList;
private TimetoLive timetoLive;

    ExampleProcess(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Service> inputCopyOnWriteArrayList,  TimetoLive timetoLive){
    this.inputCopyOnWriteArrayList = inputCopyOnWriteArrayList;
    this.timetolive = timetolive;

}


//Ultimately I would call this over and over till triggered to stop ....

private void KeepCheckingTime(inputCopyOnWriteArrayList){

 for(Service service : inputCopyOnWriteArrayList){
  Long currentTime = System.currenttime();
  if(service.time - currentTime > timeTolive){
    //remove service from list 
    // logged that you kicked out service
    // maybe add service to some other list to be re processed?
  }
 }   
}
```

Example of an inefficient idea would be to do something like..

```
// create some kind of infinite loop
while(true){
 //call KeepCheckingTime(inputCopyOnWriteArrayList)
}
// If you think this is a good solution tell me why.
```

Ideally I would want a thread to call this multiple times ,but a single thread would die after it executes right? resulting in me being unable to log a failed "Service " if it was considered expired after that single thread finished execution. I know thread pools could be created but, I don't always know how many threads I need to kick off in compared to the size of the list. For example I create 5 threads in a thread pool .....they execute KeepCheckingTime. What if all my threads finish before any "Service" expire, or fail the case mentioned above.

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: I made an attempt to clear the confusion